# Doppler effect when two bodies are not moving in straight line

Tags: homework-and-exercises, doppler-effect

What is a Doppler line? Why are the velocity components taken along Doppler line as shown here?

[image]

And what is the derivation of formula
$$f_0=f \frac{v+v_1 \cos\theta_1}{v-v_2 \cos\theta_2}$$

where $f_0$ is frequency  observed by car 2 when car 1 blows horn. $f$ is the original frequency of source (horn) from car 1. $v_1$ is velocity of car 1 and $v_2$ is velocity of car 2. $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$ are shown in diagram. In diagram Car 1 shown position is position when it horned and Car 2 shown position when he receives the sound.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is a Doppler line?

It is slightly unusual terminology, but it refers to the line along which the signal propagates. I.e. the line from the emitter at the time of emission to the receiver at the time of reception. For the usual acoustic Doppler formulas the reference frame used is the frame in which the medium is at rest.

> Why are the velocity components taken along Doppler line as shown here?

Because those components are the ones that determine the wavelength of the emitted wave along the Doppler line and the rate of the receiver crossing the wavefronts.

The emitted wavelength is not constant, but varies with $\cos(\theta)$ in directions other than straight ahead. Since the “Doppler line” is not straight ahead we account for the variation in the emitted wavelength by taking the projection.

The received frequency depends not only on the wavelength, but also on how frequently the receivers path crosses the successive wave fronts. Moving parallel to a wavefront does not impact that frequency, only moving perpendicularly does. The direction perpendicular to the wavefronts is the “Doppler line”, so again we take the projection.